# Running Julia from Textmate

Tags: julia, textmate2, tmlanguage

I'm using Textmate as my code editor, and I would like to be able to run Julia from it. I have no problems saving the .jl file and sending it to the Terminal (via the Julia bundle in Textmate), but I was wondering if it is possible to make the session interactive, so, for example, the variables are stored while the session is running (so, for instance, I could send the code to Julia line by line, or have something like Rdaemon).

Answer (score 2):

I use TextMate a lot with Julia. With Julia 1.0, everything got a lot more convenient. These are basically the steps you need to do:

1. Make sure you put your code in a package.
2. Start Julia in your terminal, Then `using YourPackage; using Revise

Revise.jl makes life a lot easier. You can work in TextMate and change the code of your functions and that will automatically get reflected in your REPL session. No need to reload. So you keep all your variables.

Occasionally you have to restart because you changed the visibility of a function or a type.

I have a more [detailed explanation](https://medium.com/@Jernfrost/my-new-workflow-with-julia-1-0-99711103d97c) of my workflow in Julia 1.0 [here](https://medium.com/@Jernfrost/my-new-workflow-with-julia-1-0-99711103d97c).